# Not authorized on execute any commands on new install of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, permissions, admin

I have installed `MongoDB 3.4` on `Windows 10` and I cannot execute any commands to *view or create users*.

I have followed the documentation to the letter and read as many answers to what seems to be a common problem, but *I still cannot solve this problem*.

Any help would be appreciated. Below are the command prompt outputs:

**Command prompt 1 running with admin rights:**

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongod.exe --storageEngine mmapv1 --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db --directoryperdb -journal
```

> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.414+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=10936 port=27017 dbpath=C:\mongodb\data\db 64-bit host=Acer
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.415+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.415+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.3
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.416+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: f07437fb5a6cca07c10bafa78365456eb1d6d5e1
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.416+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.417+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.417+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.418+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.418+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.418+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.419+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.419+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "C:\mongodb\data\db", directoryPerDB: true, engine: "mmapv1", journal: { enabled: true } } }
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.429+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=C:\mongodb\data\db\journal
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.429+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover begin
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.430+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] info no lsn file in journal/ directory
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.430+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover lsn: 0
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.431+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover C:\mongodb\data\db\journal\j._0
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.480+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover applying initial journal section with sequence number 1
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.622+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover cleaning up
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.622+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.623+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] old journal file will be removed: C:\mongodb\data\db\journal\j._0
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.627+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover done
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.780+0200 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.838+0200 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.880+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.880+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.881+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:46.883+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:48.911+0200 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/mongodb/data/db/diagnostic.data'
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:48.919+0200 I INDEX    [initandlisten] allocating new ns file C:\mongodb\data\db\admin\admin.ns, filling with zeroes...
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:49.119+0200 I FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:49.399+0200 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile C:\mongodb\data\db\admin\admin.0, filling with zeroes...
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:49.401+0200 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] creating directory C:\mongodb\data\db\admin_tmp
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:49.407+0200 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile C:\mongodb\data\db\admin\admin.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.003 secs
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:49.425+0200 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: admin.system.version properties: { v: 2, key: { version: 1 }, name: "incompatible_with_version_32", ns: "admin.system.version" }
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:49.425+0200 I INDEX    [initandlisten]          building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:49.426+0200 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
>   2017-04-01T16:21:49.427+0200 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.4
>
> 2017-04-01T16:21:49.429+0200 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017

**Command prompt 2 running with admin rights:**

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.createUser( {
... user: "siteUserAdmin",
... pwd: "password",
... roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
... });
```

Error coming back is

> 2017-04-01T16:44:14.281+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] 
>       Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command 
>       { createUser: "siteUserAdmin", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ], digestPassword: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 600000.0 } } :  _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
>       DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1290:15
>       @(shell):1:1"

```
> use admin

> db.getUsers();
2017-04-01T16:52:41.537+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: not authorized on admin to execute command { usersInfo: 1.0 } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.getUsers@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1537:1
@(shell):1:1
>
```

Comment: Was the authentication enabled before?

Comment: I think the problem may be in the message is telling you that you logged into the Admin DB but do not have rights to add a user. You should make sure you are logged in as root or a superuser. If you have already enabled authentication, you need to log in as a "superuser".

Comment: What you're showing here doesn't really add up, because you're showing that you started the server without auth enabled but getting this error. It looks like you may have at some point stopped the server and started it with auth enabled, but that's not what you're showing. I'd suggest that you repeat and retrace your steps again and report back. If you can either delete the contents of your dbpath or change it to a new one and try your steps again.

Comment: @Helmy your suggestion was spot on, thank you. I did a full reboot and discovered an old Ammps instance was starting mongodb in the background. I never thought to check so thank you so much for the pointer - I have just added my first user at last ;-)